# Geoserver : create a rasterized polygon / dynamic fill for polygons with features from database

Tags: postgis, raster, geoserver, polygon, coordinate-system

I am using geoserver 2.7-SNAPSHOT, everything is working fine but I need to implement a new function or tranformation process for personnal needs. I have a map with differents base layers (provinces,neighboorhood, district...etc) and an other layer which appears upon the base layers. This layer use a dataset which is a score, corresponding to the influence of a store on a certain area. The score is from 0 to 1.07. I succeed to create a choropleth map

[image: choropleth map]

The problem is that I got one color per district (each polygon is a district) so I tried to create an heatmap but then the division isn't visible, I have a heatmap for the whole country.

What I'd like to do is having either an heatmap or at least a dynamicfill with gradient depending of the value of the feature inside each district, not a static color. So there will be different gradient to each district

To do so I tried to use a new function, using the source code for heatmap, colorramp, dynamicfillcolor that I found on geotools repositorybut I failed.

How can I implement a new function to my geoserver ?

I succeed to add a new process (and it was hard since the documentation related to geoserver is poor), but it doesn't work for a function.

Comment: Just a thought: why don't you just create the heatmap for the whole country, and then place the borders as a new layer over it in a group layer?

Comment: @ylka It's been a while since then. I chose to deal with the issue on my backend. When we move / zoom on the map a new request to Geoserver is made and the new returned raster has the correct values. I also pass the range of colors I want as parameter (adding a &colors to the api call)